# Change props from imported component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change `isBlogPage` state by `SwitchButton` which is from outside of component

**Detail**

click SwitchButton -> Change isBlogPage -> Re-render in index.js

SwitchButton.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SwitchButton = () => {
  const [isBlogPage, setisBlogPage] = useState(true);
  return (
    <button
      className="switch-button"
      onclick={() => (isBlogPage ? setisBlogPage(false) : setisBlogPage(true))}
    >
      {isBlogPage ? "To Post" : "To Blog"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default SwitchButton;
```

index.js

```
import SwitchButton from "../../components/Home/SwitchButton";

const Home = (isBlogPage) => {

...

if (isBlogPage) {
    return (
      <div className="main-body">
        <Header />
        <SwitchButton />
      </div>
    );
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Have a read of [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Try adding const [isBlogPage, setisBlogPage] = useState(true); in index file. Then pass setisBlogPage as prop function to SwitchButton. Also isBlogPage as prop variable to SwitchButton. Then inside SwitchButton use isBlogPage and setisBlogPage from props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer writing like this lifting state from parent to child, use `&&` when you want to display only one value otherwise ternary operator `:`

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SwitchButton from './Button';

function App() {
const [isBlogPage, setisBlogPage] = useState(true);

return (
<div className="main-body">
 <SwitchButton isBlogPage={isBlogPage} setisBlogPage={setisBlogPage}/>
</div>
 );
 }

 export default App
```

**Button.js**

```
 import React from "react";
 const SwitchButton = ({isBlogPage,setisBlogPage}) => {

 function handleChange(){
 setisBlogPage(prevState => !prevState)
  }

 return (
 <div className="switchbutton">
 <button className="switch-button" onClick={handleChange}>
 {isBlogPage ? "To Post" : "To Blog"}
 </button>
 </div>
 )
 }

 export default SwitchButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Basically, that means moving your state to the parent component and pass down to the child component. In your case

`index.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import SwitchButton from "../../components/Home/SwitchButton";

const Home = (isBlogPage) => {
  // "lifting state up"
  const [isBlogPage, setisBlogPage] = useState(true);
...

if (isBlogPage) {
    return (
      <div className="main-body">
        <Header />
        // pass down to child component
        <SwitchButton isBlogPage={isBlogPage} setisBlogPage={setisBlogPage} />
      </div>
    );
```

`SwitchButton.js`

```
// here, get the passed props
const SwitchButton = ({isBlogPage, setisBlogPage}) => {

  return (
    <button
      className="switch-button"
      onclick={() => (isBlogPage ? setisBlogPage(false) : setisBlogPage(true))}
    >
      {isBlogPage ? "To Post" : "To Blog"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default SwitchButton;
```